# Implementing app login and realtime communications in parallel

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

This is more of a software architecture question rather than a specific coding issue.

I'm writing an ios app that relies on instantaneous delivery of messages and events to other mobile devices subscribed to the service. I;ve enlisted socket.io for this purpose running on a node.js backend server.

The next step is a user authentication system, where I would like users to register and log-in to be able to use the service.

I would like recommendations on what is the best way to implement the functionality. Options I see are:

1. Implementing the registration/login functionality through socket.io
2. Implementing the registration/login through the same node.js backend
   application but using express.
3. Completely separating the
   registration/login from the realtime components and pointing to the same database to authenticate and transmit authentication tokens.

Primary concerns i have are maintaining the realtime latency of the application and ensuring  security.
Assume everything is done over TLS

Comment: I don't know if this is the "best" solution, but in my current app, I'm doing authentication/login via Socket.io. This way I don't need to deal with multiple connections per client, etc., it's all just going through the same socket object. Since Socket.io defaults to SSL when the page is accessed through HTTPS, that's not a security risk (AFAIK), and while I'm not sure of the latency, Socket.io is designed to handle real-time applications, so I'd assume it's nothing significant.

Answer (score 0):

of course, you can implement those things with socket.io and express.

Here I would like to include a link. Where you can see how simply a real-time application you can build.

[Simple real-time application using socket-io](https://github.com/MujthabaAP/socketio-with-pgnotify)

### Sample code:-

server side:

```
//-----------------Dependencies------------------
var app     =     require("express")();
var pgsql   =     require("pg");
var http    =     require('http').Server(app);
var io      =     require("socket.io")(http);
//------------------------------------------------

const con = new pgsql.Pool({
 user: 'postgres',
 host: 'localhost',
 database: 'fbstatus',
 password: 'postgres',
 port: '5432'
});

app.get("/",function(req,res){
 res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
 console.log('listening on *:3000');
});

// Connect to Postgres
con.connect(function(err, client) {
 if(err) {
  console.log(err);
 }

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

 // Listen for all pg_notify channel messages
 client.on('notification', function(msg) {
  console.log(msg);
  socket.emit('update', msg);
 });

 // Designate which channels we are listening on. Add additional 
 channels with multiple lines.
 client.query('LISTEN notification_events');
 });
});
```

Client side:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <h1>real time data recieved from server</h1>
  <p>When you insert a new row into database, the below p tag 
  content will be changed</p>
  <p id="socketio"></p>
</body>
<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.2.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io.connect('http://localhost');
  socket.on('update', function (data) {
    var data_got=JSON.parse(data.payload)
    console.log(data_got["data"]["id"]);
    document.getElementById("socketio").innerHTML = data.payload;
  });
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have the socket.io portion of this app working already. The question is how and if I should combine the login/registration functionality cleanly